# How to save special array data into Three MySQL table in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, mysqli

I have JSON which need to insert into MySQL table.

What I already did is, convert it to array using:

```
$json_data = json_decode($geo_json, true);
```

and get an output of array but I do not know how to inset into second and third MySQL table.

My MySQL Table:

Table 1:

```
geo_id | user_id | geo_title | geo_description | geo_date |geo_status |geo_action |action_reason | geo_json | remote_ip | map_type |geo_snapshot
```

I can able to insert into above table easily but problem is in table two and Three listed below.

Table 2:

```
id | layer_id | map_id | layer_name | user_id | draw_type | latlng | radious
```

Table 3:

```
data_id | geo_key | geo_value | map_id | layer_id
```

Array I am getting:

```
Array
(
    [type] => FeatureCollection
    [features] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [type] => Feature
                    [properties] => Array
                        (
                            [action] => a
                            [poi_name] => a
                            [fac_type] => 17
                            [ph_number] => a
                            [hno] => a
                            [postcode] => a
                            [mail] => a
                            [str_nm] => a
                            [photo] => developer-page.png
                            [comment] => a
                            [url] => a
                            [sub_loc] => a
                            [employee] => a
                        )

                    [geometry] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => Point
                            [coordinates] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 88.434448242188
                                    [1] => 22.510971144638
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [type] => Feature
                    [properties] => Array
                        (
                            [action] => b
                            [poi_name] => b
                            [fac_type] => 18
                            [ph_number] => b
                            [hno] => b
                            [postcode] => b
                            [mail] => b
                            [str_nm] => b
                            [photo] => 1475131600_developer-page.png
                            [comment] => b
                            [url] => b
                            [sub_loc] => b
                            [employee] => b
                        )

                    [geometry] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => Point
                            [coordinates] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 88.321151733398
                                    [1] => 22.50906814933
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Now problem is to insert above data into two separate tables:

Table 2: This is only require to insert `draw_type | latlng` from above php array.

Example: `draw_ type: point and latlng : coordinates`

Table 3: 
This is require to insert `geo_key | geo_value | map_id | layer_id` from above PHP array. 
Example:

```
geo_key : properties [action,poi_name,fac_type,ph_number,hno,postcode,mail,str_nm, photo, comment, url, sub_loc, employee]

geo_value : [properties values ] 

map_id :[this will be table 1 insert id] 

layer_id : [this can be blank]
```

Please guide me and show me how to start.

Comment: Are you asking how to extract data from an array by providing specific index value?

Comment: Do you know how to use a `foreach` statement?

Comment: @HZS I want to know how to insert those above array data into MySQL three different tables as mention fields. You can see there is three different table with different approach. Third table is only accept key :  value data.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I know foreach stateemnt. please show me how foreach statement help here using example.

Comment: Thats not how SO works. You show us what you have tried, tell us where you have a problem and we help with that problem. **We dont work from specifications SO is not a free coding service**

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I am not asking you to do above code for Free. I want a simple guide about how to insert above **like array structure** into three different tables and one of those is Key value concept table which need to insert value from [properties] array inside of a multi-dimensional array. I am asking for help about how I insert above **like array** into MySQL table. I need an **example** not free code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$json_data["features"][$array_index]["geometry"]["type"]

For table2:

```
foreach($json_data["features"] as $info){
    $type = $info["geometry"]["type"];
    $latlng_0 = $info["geometry"]["coordinates"][0];
    $latlng_1 = $info["geometry"]["coordinates"][1];

    // DO INSRET with $type, $latling_0, $latling_1
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Table2 (draw_type, latlng0, latlng1) VALUES ('".$type."','".$latlng_0."','".$latlng_1."')";
    ....
}
```

For table3:

Is 'map_id' a auto increment key in table1?

You'll need to know map_id first by select * where (conditions) 
after successful insert data to table1

And if 'layer_id' can accept blank (null) data, it'll be fine if you don't specific value in INSERT command. Just make sure your table have correct settings.

Comment: Thank you @HZS you really great.... I make it work and able to get all data easily :
`foreach($json_data["features"] as $info){
   echo $type = $info["geometry"]["type"].'<br>';
   echo $latlng_0 = $info["geometry"]["coordinates"][0].'<br>';
   echo  $latlng_1 = $info["geometry"]["coordinates"][1].'<br>';
   foreach($info["properties"] as $mydata => $value){
   echo $action = $mydata.'<br>';
}
}`